# Kendo dropdown on changing value cannot bind to view model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have got problem with setting selected value of view model when changing option in dropdown.
I do not want to describe it because it will be easier just to show code by http://jsbin.com/ritor/9/edit

Just want to mention about what is wrong

When I am changing dropdown value there is a error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and view-model value is unchanged.

I have no idea what is going wrong with my code.

---

Solution:

Ok a little change make code works:
http://jsbin.com/deyuse/8/edit

Answer (score 0):

You have told the drop down list template to bind to a value that it does not have context to. Additionally, you have told the grid column to bind to the incorrect value. It should be `selectedValue` not `FieldValue`. Why is `fieldValues` a function?

Furthermore, you are trying to implement an editable grid. Your implementation is not configured for that. Please follow the documentation at Kendo UI.

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/baceqano/4/edit?html,js,output) your corrected JsBin example.

**Update**: After deeper review, your implementation needs considerable refactoring. I've revised my answer.

Comment: But in these case bindings not working. Look at the dropdown selected value and what data comes from 'mydata' object

Comment: Thank You, It looks working but you have changed way of presenting data and way of implementation. I want to do it the way of data- bindings and without allowing user to edit fields. And what is most important there is no model in your solution. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/deyuse/6/edit look here for what I wanted to achieve. Now it is working way I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. However, I don't understand what you mean when you say you don't want the user to edit the grid, but, you present them with editable controls like check boxes and drop down lists. As for there being no model, you'll find situations like this where a model won't work in conjunction with `data-` attributes (especially in cases that use templates).